# Could you correct me if I'm wrong

Tags: simplified-characters, conversation

Is it natural to say:

我不知道你为什么不常回我信息 (I don't know why you take so long to text me back).

Comment: 我不知道你为什么不常回我信息 is I don't know why you don't reply my text often (or every time).
I don't know why you take so long to text me back is 我不明白(or知道)为什么你回我的短信(or信息)要那么久
or you could say alternatively 您回一次短信也太久了吧.

Comment: Despite "我不知道你为什么不常回我信息" and "I don't know why you take so long to text me back" do not match, 我不知道你为什么不常回我信息 is in correct form.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could I also say: 我不明白为什么你那么很少回我的信息。? Sorry for being annoying, I'm just practising

Comment: Nah, you are good. 那么 and 很 are both adverbs so it's better just use one of them. 为什么你很少回我的信息 looks neat to me. 为什么你那么少回我的信息 is a bit... not that natural here though. 为什么你回我的信息那么少 feels better.

Comment: Please write a title that is descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is fine. 我不知道你为什么不常回我信息. However, your English translation doesn't match with your Chinese sentence.

> I don't know why you take so long to text me back.

我不知道你为什么不常回我信息. means **I don't know why you don't text me back usually**.

The neat way to say "why you don't text me back usually":

1. 你怎么总不回我信息呢？
2. 你怎么老不回我信息呢？
3. 你为啥经常不回我信息？
4. 你为啥总不回我信息？

The way to say "I don't know why you take so long to text me back":

1. 你为什么信息回得这么慢！
2. the one like Pedroski suggested: 我想不通为什么你回复我的信息要这么久！

Comment: 我不知道你为什么不常回我信息 suggests the person doesn't reply every text.
I don't know why you take so long to text me back suggest the person replies every text with considerable latency.

我不知道你为什么不常回我信息 is fine. However the Chinese sentence and English sentence do not translate to each other.

Comment: @Nathan, just realize that mismatch and updated.

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like:

我想不通为什么你回复我的信息要这么久！

Comment: Maybe he doesn't want to express anger... 想不通 often appears in altercations or pre-altercations...